# How to set camera, to move every second frame, to get 12fps animation feeling, and keep 24fps grease pencil animation

Tags: animation, camera, grease-pencil

I am quite new to blender and I would like to ask, if it's possible to set camera movement so that it could move every second keyframe(on twos). I have made 24fps grease pencil animation where one movement lasts for example 3 frames, other 5 frames, but it's just a sketch for now and I plan to make an animation on twos based on it. Therefore I need to make my camera also move on twos. I sincerely thank You in advance for Your help and understanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's quite easy.

Assuming you have already keyed motion for your camera, open up the *Graph Editor*.

[image]

With your Camera object selected you can use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all of its keyframes in the graph editor window.  Add a *Stepped Interpolation F-Curve Modifier* with a step size of 2.

[image]

This window is found in the N-panel, fyi.

This just adds the modifier to one channel, so you can use those two buttons in the top right to first copy, and then paste that modifier to all channels.

[image]

[image]

This does add an extra modifier on the currently selected channel.  I don't think you're allowed to have duplicates so it's disabled and doesn't matter, but for completeness sake I guess I should advise to delete it.

I suppose in the event that a new channel gets keyed you'd just have to remember to go add this modifier.  Or you'd remember when the animation looks off. ;)

Comment: Thank You so much!!! It worked :D